# How the UNDO and REDO feature in any TEXT EDITOR is implemented?

Tags: algorithm, text, undo, undo-redo

I am trying create my android app for creating and editing text documents. But I am stuck upon a problem of providing the **undo and redo** feature of text editor. Almost all text editors have this feature. Can someone give some pointers on how these are implemented?

I thought of creating **savepoints** like as we do in **databases** by creating redundant copies of this text document and rollback for **undo operation**.

But it would be an overkill, since we most often change few characters between each savepoint.

Can someone provide me pointers to guide in the right direction?

Also, I am not particularly interested in Android solution. Any language(c,c++,java) is also fine by me.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a tad too broad to answer. What have you tried yourself? What principles have you considered using?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern, in particular "Multi-level undo"